# Как выключить линукс из консоли

Tags: altlinux

Как выключить линукс из консоли.Перебрал уже такие команды halt,poweroff,init 0,shutdown - на все команды пишет "команда не найдена" пробовал добавлять sudo -эффект тот же,вошел под root -то же самое. OS - Simply Linux 5.0.1 Скажите как выключается это чудо из консоли

Comment: сори! нашел sudo halt выключает,пропустил второпях)))

Comment: скорее всего, это было http://altlinux.org/su-

Answer (score 3):

1. Найти абсолютный путь к утилите: $ whereis shutdown
2. Результат поиска: shutdown: /sbin/shutdown /usr/share/man/man8/shutdown.8.gz /usr/share/man/man2 shutdown.2.gz
3. Выполнить команду: $sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now

PS. Попробуйте: init 6

Answer (score 1):

sudo shutdown -h 5    выключить через 5 минут

Answer (score 1):

набрать в терминале halt

Answer (score 0):

Может извращением вида "killall системный процесс"?)))

Comment: не стоит давать такие советы даже "в шутку", это мусор

Answer (score 0):

sudo shutdown -P now

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё init.Напишите в консоли man init. Эта штука работает в SuSe и Ubuntu